# How to insert in a table having a single column which is unique?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am having a table which is having a single column which in unique as set <del>auto incremented</del> `IDENTITY` on. how to insert in that table ? or how to insert a new row in that table? i wanna use that row as a counter.

Edited:

This is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[extra](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I am using sql server.

```
insert into extra(id) values (default).
```

This query showing an error.

Comment: we would need more specifics . which rdbms and version? your question is very vague

Comment: question edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you would insert in any other table:

```
insert into [tableName] default values;
```

Comment: i cant insert a value? table having only a single column. which is auto incremented.

Comment: @waleedansari That's why the `default values` is there.